# Perl optimization: inlining a function changed the results

Tags: perl

I profiled some code, and there is one function which stood out and I was wondering if there is a way to optimize it:

The function is defined as:

```
sub convert_arrayref {
   if(ref($_[0]) eq 'ARRAY') {
       return join(($_[1] || ","), @{$_[0]});
   }
   else {
     return $_[0];
   }
}
```

Most of the times the `else` block will get executed, and I was wondering if I could inline it rather than making a function call. The calling code looks as follows:

```
$data = convert_arrayref($data, '&')
```

So, what I did was change the calling code as:

```
if ($data eq 'ARRAY') {
    $data = join('&', $data)
}
```

I thought this would be equivalent. However, the results are different. I am wondering if I have done something wrong here.

Comment: You can fold it into one line `$data = join( '&', @$data) if ref($data) eq 'ARRAY';`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get different results because you did not replicate the functionality of the `if` clause.  You need to use [ref](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/ref) to check if your variable is an array reference, and you need to deference the variable:

```
if (ref($data) eq 'ARRAY') {
    $data = join('&', @{ $data })
}
```